# Output of Restangular data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Hello I have output data from my API
I use Restangular libary

My service

```
order.getclient=function(order){
    return Restangular
    .all('/clients/'+order.client.id).customGETLIST(null, null);
};
```

My controller

```
$scope.fetchGetClient=function(){
    $scope.client = Order.getclient($scope.order).$object;
};
```

out in html

```
<div ng-init="fetchGetClient()">
    {{client}}
</div>
```

I get empty array
I also tried

```
$scope.fetchGetClient=function(){
 Order.getclient($scope.order).then(function (response) {
   $scope.client = response
   console.log(response)
 });
```

console.log also empty
thanks